# Cross-compiling R packages with Fortran shared library

Tags: r, package, fortran, cross-compiling, gfortran

I am developing an R package that relies on some Fortran subroutines. I write my code under Linux, but to be able to collaborate with my colleagues who work with Windows, I would like to be able to compile a Windows version of my package.

How to compile an R package for Windows under Linux? I have been looking into this issue on the web and found many suggestions and possible solutions, but no clear advice on how to do this with recent versions of R. It looks like cross-compiling was supported in previous versions of R, but not anymore today.

I am able to compile my Fortran subroutine for Windows under Linux using MinGW, but I am not sure about the next steps to create a package that can be installed on Windows. Does anyone have experience with this?

Any help would be much appreciated, thank you!

Comment: R itself as well as many of its packages have Fortran subroutines and are cross-compile for Linux, Mac and Windows.

Comment: Yes, but how to compile a package for Windows under Linux?

Comment: I don't think you can cross-compile a package on system A for system B. You can use the win-builder system to make a binary package for Windows. See <http://win-builder.r-project.org>